# Termination caused websites executing no more

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis-7, visual-studio-2012, signalr, terminate

I had a perfectly well running asp.net mvc application and I was debugging message sending via SignalRand I decided to stop debugging and went to edit some code. However, there was an error saying something about IIS termination and whether I want to do that because something (I assume - the application) cannot be stopped. (I am really sorry, but I didn't read it at the time). So now I try to relaunch my program and it just won't open. The website is trying to be opened but the loading circle in chrome just kept on spinning forever.

What I tried to do was:
1. restarted VS - didn't help
2. restarted PC - didn't help
3. created a new project, brought all files to it and launched it and it worked!

So then it worked for ~10 minutes or so and then just stopped again (this time no error message or anything). I tried changing a port in the settings of the project. Didn't work. Tried changing back and it launched successfully. For a minute or so... :(

So finally, I tried putting a break point right at the

```
public class MvcApplication : System.Web.HttpApplication
{
    protected void Application_Start()
 -> {
```

The breakpoint was hit, it successfully passed the next line

```
RouteTable.Routes.MapHubs();
```

and just disappeared at

```
AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
```

Many times I tried and it always disappears at the same location. Going deeper is not an option since this is system method. I suspect something can be problematic with that, but I am not experienced with much configuration of asp.net.

P.S. many times VS was acting strange and even tho I set the breakpoint at the place I marked above, it showed the breakpoint with a message that it won't be hit because the source differs from the current code (But I didn't change a thing since before the very first crash! The only place I modified a few symbols at was at MyHub.cs which is an extended class for a Hub for SignalR)

Lastly, I tried deleting everything from bin folder so it got fully rebuilt, but without any success to revive my application.

What could be a possible problem, maybe someone had anything at least similar to this? Or maybe someone would be kind to help me at choosing better keywords while searching in google because "IIS termination" and "AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas(); not working" didn't bring me much :(

Comment: What happens to your `w3wp.exe` instance? What does IIS Manager say about your Application Pool? Is anything in the Windows Application or System event logs?

Comment: Have tried running your application from another web server? like iis express?

Comment: @Dai, w3wp.exe is not visible in task manager (if I understood correctly where to look for it). I checked the logs, there was nothing related. And the IIS Manager seems normal, the same like yesterday.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a known bug: https://github.com/SignalR/SignalR/issues/1335.

We have been unable to successfully reproduce this issue on our servers.  We've seen that using a different web server will resolve the issue.  If you're able to post a reproduction project to the linked Issue, chances are it will be resolved promptly.

Comment: Thanks for the link. It really seems like this is THE issue I am having. I killed iisexpress.exe and this time it ran successfully!

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, the solution I marked isn't the exact thing that helped me. [This link](http://forums.asp.net/post/5291645.aspx) was the thing that miraculously helped me and I was able to finally get back to work. However, I found the winning link because of N. Taylor Mullen, so he deserves the full credit :) But letting others know if anyone comes to this question :)